# Github page showing 404 after following instructions?

Tags: github, github-pages

This should be url of website:

https://artnomadproject.github.io/

I have made an organization with the exact same name as repository

https://github.com/artnomadproject/artnomadproject

and added `index.html` with `Hello world` inside:
https://github.com/artnomadproject/artnomadproject/blob/master/index.html

Where did I go wrong?

this are the steps I did:
https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a GitHub pages project site, available at http://username.github.io/repository.

In your case: https://artnomadproject.github.io/artnomadproject

It is not a GitHub pages User site, which would be at https://username.github.io.
For https://artnomadproject.github.io/ to be filled out, you would need a https://github.com/username/username.github.io repo.

In both instances, make sure you

- have [configured the publishing source](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/select-master-branch-docs-folder-as-source.png]

- have [selected a theme](https://blog.github.com/2017-11-29-use-any-theme-with-github-pages/) with the [theme chooser](https://blog.github.com/2016-12-15-new-theme-chooser-for-github-pages/)

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/849592/21229008/24006df6-c2ae-11e6-94a4-ca4eb085f5f4.png]

Comment: Thank you. Can you add to your answer that you need to choose a Theme in setting for the page to work. Only I did that did hello world appear